# Start Alacritty with Override Options

Tags: alacritty

I'm trying to use Alacritty with some custom startup overrides. Annoyingly, setting the window size does not work. It just silently ignores it. It always opens at the same size (100x35). Note that I have not set these settings in `alacritty.yml`.

```sh
alacritty -o "window.dimensions.columns=100"
```

But some settings, like the startup mode, do work.

```sh
alacritty -o "window.startup_mode=Fullscreen"
```

Also, if I deliberately put a typo in the dimensions override ("dimensionnns"), there are no errors or changes.

```sh
alacritty -o "window.dimensionnns.columns=100"
```

Trying to set `window.dimensions.rows` does nothing as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'd love to be able to automate Alacritty's size for different projects.

Answer (score 5):

I found out that you'll need to specify both the columns and lines numbers so the proper command would be like: `alacritty -o "window.dimensions.lines=15" -o "window.dimensions.columns=60"`

Remember: both the lines and columns number must be non-zero and positive.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml

```
window:
   dimensions:
     columns: 133
     lines: 40
```

Reference.
https://github.com/tmcdonell/config-alacritty/blob/master/alacritty.yml

I struggle with this too. Be aware yml formatting is very picky as you may already know. This config works for me on Arch running GNOME40.

Comment: I just realized this is probably not the answer you were looking for as it appears you want to change it on a case by case basis. Sorry. Maybe file a bug report?

Comment: Yeah, I’m thinking at this point I will file a bug report. I’ve tried about a million (hyperbole) different permutations to try to make this work with no success.

Comment: While this answer wasn't what the OP asked, it helped me debug why my settings weren't working -- thank you! (Dimensions was commented still..)

Answer (score 0):

Just change "window.dimensions.rows=40" to "window.dimensions.lines=40" and it will work then.